# AJAX response is different from java/hibernate returned string

Tags: java, ajax, hibernate, extjs, responsetext

I've some problem with this simple server side method (java/hibernate):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Prova" ,  method=RequestMethod.POST)
@Transactional( propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<String>  Prova(
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response
        ) throws Exception
{

    log.error("Sono qui");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("pippotopolinopaperino",HttpStatus.OK);   

}
```

If the client does an AJAX request (I use ExtJs) the response is:

```
pippotopolinopa0015↵
```

WHY?

P.s sorry for my bad english

P.p.s I've tried also with:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Prova" ,  method=RequestMethod.POST)
@Transactional( propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public @ResponseBody  String   Prova(
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response
        ) throws Exception
{

    log.error("Sono qui");
    return "pippotopolinopaperino"; 

}
```

Comment: are you trying to render a template? or just want the string as response?

Comment: I just want the string!
This method is quite old and it worked very well ... until now!

Comment: did you try adding " produces = "text/plain" to your annotation @RequestMapping?

Comment: Now I'm at home without my code but tomorrow i will try! Thank in advance.

Comment: No difference adding " produces = "text/plain" to annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved in this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Prova" ,  method=RequestMethod.POST)
@Transactional( propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public @ResponseBody  List<String>   Prova(
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response
    ) throws Exception
{    
  log.error("Sono qui");
  List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
  ret.add("pippoPlutoTopolino");
  return ret;        
}
```

Or also:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Prova2" ,  method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody public StringBuffer Prova2(
        HttpServletRequest request
        ) throws Exception
{
  return new StringBuffer("pippoPlutoTopolino");  
}
```

But I don't understand why doesn't work returning a simple String.